# ImportError: cannot import name _NONE

Tags: python, gevent

For some reason I'm getting this error when trying to import `gevent` inside my docker container:

```
# python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02)
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gevent
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from gevent.hub import get_hub, iwait, wait
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 31, in <module>
    from gevent._util import _NONE
ImportError: cannot import name _NONE
>>>
```

Which is odd because `_util.py` exists, it's in the `dist-packages/gevent` directory. When I did a `pip install` on another system, it works fine.

Anyone have any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

Have you upgraded `gevent` package recently or maybe installed it over old version?
I ran `pip install --ignore-installed gevent` to update old version of this package in my virtualenv, and then this error starts to appear.

I fixed it with `pip uninstall gevent` (two times to completely remove it) followed by `pip install gevent`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you import gevnet this module is not you see it.
you can print something in you `_util.py` module.
if nothing print, I guess `"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py"` import `_util` is not in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevnet`, and you can try to print sys.path to find real import path and fix it.

---

In my Method：

- 1. uninstall gevent.
- 2. use a another system gevnet or virtualenv package,and copy to you real（I guess you have a env path like '/usr/local/lib64'）
- 3. exec `python -c 'import gevent'` test is ok.